# How do I set the window title of a QEMU session?

Tags: qemu, titlebar

I am making a demonstration of some different [bootloaders](http://3zanders.co.uk/2017/10/13/writing-a-bootloader/). I want to run all four at the same time, if they're all named QEMU, how can you tell which is which? I prefer to set the titlebar, so I don't interfere with the bootloader. If it helps, I am using `qemu-system-x86_64` on `wsl -d ubuntu`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `-name` option to the QEMU command-line.  The VM window title will look like:

```
QEMU ("Your guest VM name")
```

From [the documentation](https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/invocation.html):

> -name name
>
> > Sets the name of the guest. This name will be displayed in the SDL window caption. The name will also be used for the VNC server. Also optionally set the top visible process name in Linux. Naming of individual threads can also be enabled on Linux to aid debugging.